# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddGraphQL' and no accessible extension method 'AddGraphQL' in GraphQL 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, graphql

Along with GRaphQL 5.1.1 on Asp.net Core 6.4, I got an exception where:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{ ---
  services.AddScoped<TopicSchema>();
  services.AddGraphQL().AddSystemTextJson().AddGraphTypes(typeof(TopicSchema),     
      ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
   ---
}
```

How to resolve this exception?

There might be either new nuget package which has to be installed with right version or AddGraphQL in other cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure install package `GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore` and `GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore.SystemTextJson`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore" Version="5.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Transports.AspNetCore.SystemTextJson" Version="5.1.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And import the namespace like below:

```
using GraphQL.Server;  //import the namespace...

services.AddGraphQL().AddSystemTextJson().AddGraphTypes(typeof(TopicSchema),
     ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
```